# Java - what is the stream of PrintStream of the System.out?

Tags: java

I want to understand java streams.

The code :

```
System.out.println(System.out.getClass().getCanonicalName())
```

outputs

```
java.io.PrintStream
```

As I understood PrintStream is the wrapper of another stream to add functionality of formating. But I can't understand what is the stream class that is wrapped by PrintStream? Is this Console? And how to check it - from PrintStream API I didn't find any suitable method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following blog post: [How System.out.println() really works](https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/).

If you look at the Open JDK code of [java.lang.System](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.0out) you see at line 100 that it is initialized with the `nullPrintStream()` and in the `initializeSystemClass()` function at line 1095 it is set to a wrapped `fdOut`. And `fdOut` is just the handle to the standard output stream, see the code of [java.io.FileDescriptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileDescriptor.java#FileDescriptor) at line 85.

So there isn't that much magic.

Answer (score 4):

This is the point of having an API. At some level, the actual "stream" becomes OS and platform dependent. But Java has been set up so that you don't have to worry about such things

Comment: If he is interested in such things, he can still ask for it.

Comment: If it is so platform dependent then how Console class was implemented?

Comment: I can't accept this answer. Java is not the type of language where we can say - don't worry about it. It is a professional language so here everything must be clear at the lowest levels.

Answer (score 0):

The `PrintStream` uses a `BufferedWriter textOut` and an `OutputStreamWriter charOut`. For printing a line the following code is executed:

```
private void println() {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (out == null)
                throw new IOException("Stream closed");
            textOut.newLine();
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush)
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

where out is an `OutputStream`.

Comment: "out is an OutputStream" - yes. But I think OP's question is about which implementing class it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately all streams are character/byte based streams. Things like Print Writer are wrappers on that so that you can do things based on other data types that you are comfortable with rather than every time converting your data into character/byte types.

Answer (score 0):

It wraps a FileOutputStream that is tied to the console output.